# How To Cast Float to Integer?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm stuck on casting Float to Integer in below function - it never comes to `v.to_int`
(sorry, I'm novice in Ruby and it is a monkey coding).
Issue I'm trying to resolve is data that comes from MongoDB supposed to be of  Type Integer, but sometimes there are Floats in input stream(see below).

What I'm trying to achieve - when Integer expected on particular position - Cast and Truncate to Integer whatever comes there(usually Float).

```
def transform_primitive(v, type=nil)
  case v
  when BSON::ObjectId, Symbol
    v.to_s
  when BSON::Binary
    if type.downcase == 'uuid'
      v.data.to_s.unpack("H*").first
    else
      Sequel::SQL::Blob.new(v.data.to_s)
    end
  when Mongo::DBRef
    v.id.to_s
  when Integer
    v.to_int
  else
    v
  end
end
```

input looks like below, so last value `150.0` expected to be `150`

```
[ "EUR",  20]
[ "EUR",  30]
[ "EUR",  450]
[ "EUR",  22]
[ "EUR",  150.0]
```

Used Ruby 2.7 MongoDB 3.4
Source Library (MoSQL) is not mine, repo is [here](https://github.com/stripe/mosql/blob/master/lib/mosql/schema.rb)

Comment: Well, `when Integer` matches integers, not floats.

Comment: The `v.to_int` is useless, since you are only calling it when the value is *already* an `Integer`, it *literally* says so in your code: "`when Integer` then `v.to_int`".

Answer (score 5):

To match both integers and floats you need to change the when condition to:

```
when Integer, Float
```

Or just `when Float` as the Integer case is covered by the `else` already.

Observe:

```
3.is_a? Integer #=> true
3.is_a? Float #=> false
3.4.is_a? Integer #=> false
3.4.is_a? Float #=> true
```

Alternatively you can use the class Numeric:

```
when Numeric
```

Note that Numeric includes not only integers and floats but also complex and rational numbers:

```
(1+0i).is_a? Numeric
```

I think this should be ok in your case, but just pointing it out.

Btw, instead of `to_int` you may want to use `round`:

```
3.4.to_i #=> 3
3.6.to_i #=> 3
3.4.round #=> 3
3.6.round #=> 4
```